# Не работает password_verify() в PHP

Tags: php, авторизация, регистрация, password-hash

Уважаемые любители и профессионалы, подскажите пожалуйста, где собака зарыта?

Есть обработчики регистрации и авторизации (в одном файле) и всё работает отлично кроме одного - пишет НЕ ВЕРНЫЙ ЛОГИН ИЛИ ПАРОЛЬ

Вот код:

```
//Регистрация пользователей
function checkUser($mysqli, $login, $name) {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login=? or name=?"); 
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $login, $name);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    return $result->fetch_assoc();
}
function regUser($mysqli, $login, $pass, $name, $status) {
    //$pass = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`login`, `name`, `pass`, `status`, `regdate`) VALUES(?,?,?,?, NOW())";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql); 
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $login, $pass, $name, $status);
    $stmt->execute();
}
$errors = [];
$meslogin = [];
$usercheck = checkUser($mysqli, $_POST['login'], $_POST['name']);
if ($usercheck && isset($_POST['reg'])) {
    if($_POST['login'] == ''){
        $errors[] = "Введите логин";
    }
    if($_POST['name'] == ''){
        $errors[] = "Введите отображаемое имя";
    }
    if($_POST['pass'] == ''){
        $errors[] = "Введите пароль";
    }
    if ($usercheck['login'] == $_POST['login']) {
        $errors[] = "Введённый логин уже занят";
    }
    if ($usercheck['name'] == $_POST['name']) {
        $errors[] = "Введённое имя уже занято";
    }
}
if (isset($_POST['reg']) && !$errors) {
    regUser($mysqli, $_POST['login'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['pass'], $_POST['status']);
    echo "<script>alert('Регистрация успешно завершена! Войдите используя ваш логин и пароль.')</script>";;
} else {
    $error = '<div id="errors">'.array_shift($errors).'</div>';
}

//авторизация пользователей
function loginIn($mysqli, $login, $pass){
    $logins = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login=? AND pass=?");
    //$pass = password_verify($_POST['pass'], $user['pass']);
    $logins->bind_param("ss", $login, $pass);
    $logins->execute();
    $resultlogin = $logins->get_result();
    return $resultlogin->fetch_assoc();
}
$logs = loginIn($mysqli, $_POST['loginlog'], $_POST['passlog']);
    if (isset($_POST['reglog'])) {
    if($_POST['loginlog'] == ''){
        $errors[] = "Вы не ввели логин";
    }
    if($_POST['passlog'] == ''){
        $errors[] = "Вы не ввели пароль";
    }
    if($logs['login'] != $_POST['loginlog']){
        $errors[] = "Неверный логин или пароль";
    }
    if($logs['pass'] != $_POST['passlog']){
        $errors[] = "Неверный пароль или пароль";
    }
    if (!$errors && $logs) {
        $_SESSION['USER_NAME'] = $logs['name'];
        $_SESSION['USER_REGDATE'] = $logs['regdate'];
        $_SESSION['USER_LOGIN'] = 1;
        $_SESSION['LOGIN'] = 1;
        exit(header('Location: /'));
    } else {
        $error = '<div id="errors">'.array_shift($errors).'</div>';
    }
}
```

ОДИН МОМЕНТ - сейчас пароли находятся в базе в в том виде, в каком их вводили пользователи, так как функция **password_hash** закомментирована (если раскомментировать, то она хэширует всё как надо в базе и вопросов нет).

Вопрос касается функции **password_verify**, дело всё в ней я подозреваю.

Помогите пожалуйста решить вопрос, так как при хэшировании выдаёт НЕ ВЕРНЫЙ ЛОГИН ИЛИ ПАРОЛЬ

Comment: password_verify возвращает true или false, и вы зачем-то ищете этот true/false в базе, конечно же совпадений никогда найдено не будет.

Comment: @andreymal, а можете поконкретней объяснить что я нет так делаю?

Answer (score 3):

Функция `password_verify()` принимает два аргумента, строка пароля "12345" и хеш данного пароля от функции `password_hash()`. То есть вам нужно изменить код добавления пароля в базу данных:

```
function regUser($mysqli, $login, $name, $pass) {
    $pass = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`login`, `name`, `pass`, `regdate`) VALUES(?,?,?, NOW())";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql); 
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $login, $name, $pass);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

и тогда вы сможете использовать `password_verify()`

Comment: то есть мне нужно как то по другому переписать функцию regUser??? Вопросы мои глупые, так как я молод и ясен ещё в php)

Comment: Вы можете просто скопировать мой код и вставить вместо своей функции, роскоментировать строку с верификацией пароля и все должно заработать, по сути все изменения были заделаны вот тут https://i.imgur.com/y2yVI1E.png

Comment: К сожалению НЕ ВЕРНЫЙ ЛОГИН ИЛИ ПАРОЛЬ

Comment: У вас в методе loginIn неверный if https://i.imgur.com/LDzqToY.png , вместо ```if($logs['pass'] != $_POST['pass']){``` замените на ```if(password_verify($_POST['pass'], $logs['pass']) === true){```

Comment: И так, функция немного исправлена, новые данные вверху в основном вопросе. И подскажите пожалуйста ,что за 123 после открытия фигурной скобки условия? С этим 123 вылазит синтаксическая ошибка.

Comment: 123 это пример https://i.imgur.com/8cnnBrD.png , сейчас не могу понять, что именно у вас не выходит. Если в базе храниться пароль в первичном виде, нужно их все хэшировать, после того изменить regUser метод как в ответе выше, и  поменять if как в комментарии к этому ответу.

Answer (score 0):

В 99 случаев из ста, если `password_verify()` возвращает false, это значит, что в БД для хэша выделено поле недостаточной длины. Она должна быть как минимум 60, но лучше сразу сделать varchar(255) на будущее.

В остальных случаях это либо просто путаница, когда пользователь перепутал пароли, либо какая-нибудь кривая функция, которая зачем-то портит пароль перед хэшированием.

Как убедиться, что с `password_verify()` всё в порядке, а проблема в вашем собственном коде?

1. Выведите на экран значения пароля и хэша в скрипте регистрации **перед** сохранением в базу, и скопируйте результат в какой-нибудь текстовый файл:

   ```
    var_dump($password);
    $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    var_dump($hash);
   ```
2. Во время логина точно так же, выведите введенный пользователем пароль и полученный из БД хэш:

   ```
    var_dump($password);
    var_dump($row['password']);
    if(password_verify($password, $row['password'])) ...
   ```

И просто глазами сравните с ранее сохраненными значениями.

- если пароли и хэши совпадают, это значит что `password_verify()` вернет true
- если `password_verify()` возвращает false, это значит, что либо пароли, либо хэши при регистрации и при логине не совпадают. И вам надо разобраться - почему.